# Serve static directory with dynamic URL query parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url, routes

I am trying to serve a static directory dynamically by adding a pathname parameter to the URL.

I am able to serve the directory just fine with the following line, which renders the html and subdirectories in the browser without having to readFile etc:

```
app.use('/', express.static('/Users/virtuload-beta/backend/uploads/folder/subfolder/'))
```

This helped for testing but I need it to be dynamic as I am getting the directory name depending on a path variable from MongoDB, and then serving the directory based on the URL.

I've tried multiple solutions, this is my current one:

- app.js:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../uploads', )), serveRouter)
```

- routes.js:

```
router.get('/:id', FileCtrl.servepath);
```

-FileCtrl.js:

```
const servepath = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let id = req.params.id 
    Upload.findById(id)
          .populate('Upload')
          .select('relPath') //relPath = /folder/subfolder
          .exec(function(err, upload) {
            if (err) {
              res.send(err)
            } else {
              const filepath = `${upload.relPath}`        
              console.log(filepath)    //logs folder/subfolder 
            //parse http object coming from client
              const urlObject = url.parse(req.url, true)
              console.log(urlObject)

              var myUrl = new URL(`http://localhost:8000/static/${filepath}`)
              return myUrl;
            }
          })
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
      }
}
```

I'm not getting any error but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulate the `req.url` and return `next()`

First your route

```
router.get('/:id', FileCtrl.servepath);
```

Controller(added`next`):

```
const servepath = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let id = req.params.id
    Upload.findById(id)
      .populate('Upload')
      .select('relPath') //relPath = /folder/subfolder
      .exec(function (err, upload) {
        if (err) {
          res.send(err)
        } else {
          const filepath = `${upload.relPath}`
          req.url = `/static/${pathfile}/index.html`
          return next();
        }
      })
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

Last your static route (note: define it after all other routes)

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../uploads')), serveRouter)
```

Comment: It's still not working, it says cannot get with status 404

Comment: put this for static route to log the modified url `app.use(function (req, res, next) {console.log(req.url); next();});` is the url correct?

Comment: I understand that this should work as when I console.log(req.url) (while req.url = `/${pathfile}` is commented out) I get the user id param as specified in the original url, and when I console.log(req.url) with req.url = `/${pathfile}`, I get the directory path. Yet, it still doesnt work

Comment: Is `/${pathfile}` not a static file?

Comment: It's a directory containing an index.html file. This only time I can get it to render is with this line of code: 
```
app2.use('/', express.static('/Users/virtuload-beta/backend/uploads/folder/subfolder'))

```
As soon as I try to make it dynamic it says "cannot get"

Comment: Did you try `/static/${pathfile}`? And also log the reg.url with that snippet I send and tell what is logging.

Comment: Yes I tried that, it doesn't load the files. When I log the req.url I get "/e5761540b328786dadcc9f9568a39de81568896406532/Nancy_Collins_118226967_v2" (These are the actual names of the folder and subfolder). The error reads: 
'GET / 404 15.051 ms - 139'

Comment: Your route us listening to `/static/` and by the it needs a file specified. So it should be `/static/${pathfile}/index.html`.